# Showing $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{xy^4}{x^2+y^8}$ Exists and Does Not Exist...

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Consider the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{xy^4}{x^2+y^8}$$

Although Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica say that the limit is [zero](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(x,y)+to+(0,0)+(xy%5E4)%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E8)), consider the limits along the paths $y=0$ and $x=y^4$.

If $y=0$, then the limit becomes $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{x^2}=0$$

However, if $x=y^4$, then the limit becomes $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^8}{2y^8}=1/2$$

Therefore, the limit **does not exist.**

On the other hand, when I switch to polar coordinates, $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$, the limit becomes $$\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{r^5\cos\theta \sin^4\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta +r^8\sin^8\theta }=\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{r^3\cos\theta\sin^4\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^6\sin^8\theta}=\frac{0}{\cos^2 \theta}$$

**Case 1:** If  $\cos^6 \theta \not=0$, then the limit is zero.

**Case 2:** If $\cos^6\theta=0$, then (since this implies $\sin^8\theta=1$) the limit is $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^3 (0) (1)}{0+r^6 (1)}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{0}{r^6}=0$$

Therefore, according to my work in polar coordinates and Mathematica the **limit is zero**. However, I have found two different paths $y=0$ and $x=y^4$ for which the limits are distinct.

Does this limit exist, and where is the error?

Comment: Yes, dont trust mathematica or wolframalpha.

Comment: This limit pretty obviously doesn't exist.  Consider approaching from $y=x$ then the limit diverges and you're done.  Lots of computer algebra systems are terrible at finding limits of multivariable functions precisely because you can screw up very easily.

Comment: @Masacroso What about polar?

Comment: Can you please elaborate  on the $\cos^6(\theta) \neq 0$ parts.. it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla If $\cos^6$ is nonzero, then the numberator is zero while the denonomator is nonzero, so the entire fraction is zero. In case 2, I argued that the limit is still 0 even when $\cos^6 = 0$.

Comment: @TheSubstitute the paths that you chosen from polar coordinates converge to zero but you previously shown that the limit can be $1/2$, this is enough to see that the limit doesnt exists.

Comment: @Masacroso I don't want the final answer to depend on the technique I am using.

Comment: @TheSubstitute the reason your work with polar coordinate doesn't work is you're assuming that $\theta$ is constant which is not correct.  $\theta$ is allowed to vary as well as $r$.

Comment: @TheSubstitute a general technique to prove that these limits doesnt exists is define a variable $z:=y/x$, then $z\to c$ for any $c$ at the same time that $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, then you can play with this kind of sequences. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2157754/173262). But setting $x=y^4$ is enough as you shown before and simple.

Comment: @TheSubstitute This is one of those rare examples where the limit along any straight line into the origin is the same and the limit still does not exist. Your methods do not conflict, the second is just not strong enough to prove that the limit exists (it's great for proving it doesn't exist when it works, though).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit $\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$ is found using polar coordinates but it is not supposed to exist.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753381/limit-fracx2yx4y2-is-found-using-polar-coordinates-but-it-is-not-supp)